# I cannot access variables from start method in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use the video01, video02, and video03 variable in the void update() method. I cannot use int, float, boolean, to make it into a global variable. I cannot add before the start method because it tends to throw errors if I do it like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class VideoPlayback : MonoBehaviour
{
    //this is video #1
    public GameObject preIntro;
    //this is video #2
    public GameObject gameFreak;
    //this is video #3
    public GameObject charizardScreen;

    private video1 = preIntro.GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
    private video2 = gameFreak.GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
    private video3 = charizardScreen.GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
    
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
       if(video01.isPlaying == true)
       {
             
       }else
       {
       
       }
    }
}
```

if I do it like the one below it shows me this error can you give me an answer

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class VideoPlayback : MonoBehaviour
{
    //this is video #1
    public GameObject preIntro;
    //this is video #2
    public GameObject gameFreak;
    //this is video #3
    public GameObject charizardScreen;

    
    void Start()
    {
        //getting a unity video component for each video
        var video1 = preIntro.GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
        var video2 = gameFreak.GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
        var video3 = charizardScreen.GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
       if(video01.isPlaying == true)
       {
             
       }else
       {
       
       }
    }
}
```

Error:
`this variable has not been defined in this context`

Comment: *Where* you declare a variable determines its ***scope*** or where it exists.  You declared them in `Start` so that is the only context they exist in.  Required reading: **[Scope and Visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/scope-and-visibility?view=msvc-160)**

Comment: You have to declare video1, video2 and video3 has member-variables of the class. So you have to put them at the same position like preIntro, gameFreak etc. on the top.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment you would want to set the videos (probably as private members) of this script. Remove var for each one in the start method is also required else you will get a null exception instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your members storing the videos in your class, in order to use them in different methods (`Start` and `Update`).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class VideoPlayback : MonoBehaviour
{
    //this is video #1
    public GameObject preIntro;
    //this is video #2
    public GameObject gameFreak;
    //this is video #3
    public GameObject charizardScreen;

    private VideoPlayer video1;
    private VideoPlayer video2;
    private VideoPlayer video3;

    void Start()
    {
        //getting a unity video component for each video
        video1 = preIntro.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        video2 = gameFreak.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        video3 = charizardScreen.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
       if(video01.isPlaying)
       {
             
       }else
       {
       
       }
    }
}
```

If you do not need the videos' `GameObject`s, but only their `VideoPlayer` components you can simply declare the members as

```
[SerializeField] private VideoPlayer video1;
[SerializeField] private VideoPlayer video2;
[SerializeField] private VideoPlayer video3;
```

and link them directly in the inspector (as you are doing with the `GameObject`s currently).

Comment: thanks a lot this helped me a lot I didn't know about the video library